# i m trying to run a command Discord.js but error appear "TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

below there is a code hope someone helps me :)
i tried to search on google but didnt find any solutions

```cs
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

  module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    const snipes = bot.snipes.get(message.channel.id) || [];
    const msg = snipes[args[0] - 1 || 0];
    if (!msg) return message.channel.send(`That is not a valid snipe...`);
    const Embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setAuthor(
        msg.author.tag,
        msg.author.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true, size: 256 })
      )
      .setDescription(msg.content)
      .setFooter(`Date: ${msg.date} | ${args[0] || 1}/${snipes.length}`);
    if (msg.attachment) Embed.setImage(msg.attachment);
    message.channel.send(Embed);
  },
  module.exports.help = {
    name: "snipe",
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is normal for you to attach the error's location (usually in the form `error: 53,23` so users can find it more easily.

First of all, undefined errors are the most common errors you will get ([please read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_defined)). They occur when you either havent declared a variable, or a method you have used is incorrect. In this case, I believe it is coming from this line:

```js
const snipes = bot.snipes.get(message.channel.id) || [];
```

I don't know what `snipes` is but in v12 we use `cache`, and `#get` is out of use as per ([also read](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html#collection))

If I knew what snipes was I could tell you what the right code is, but I do not. Please use the info attached to see if you can solve the issue.